# Wanted alternative to heketi which will provide REST service for glusterfs

Tags: glusterfs

I am searching for alternative to heketi to provide RESTful management interface to manager the gluserfs servers.
We are already using heketi but somehow it is still unable to remove mount points in glusterfs server.I am unable to find the alternative to heketi. Has anyone came across any alternative to heketi?

Comment: Same here, a shame for heketi, it make me fear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GlusterD2](https://github.com/gluster/glusterd2) is the new RESTful management interface that will become the default during the next 4.x Gluster release.

Comment: yea. It was experiment 5 months back.

Comment: yes, I'm sorry there was nobody to reply earlier :-/

Comment: Is this still an valid alternative, seems not much code changes are happening in the repo

Answer (score 1):

Try to read [kaDalu](https://medium.com/@tumballi/kadalu-ocean-of-potential-in-k8s-storage-a07be1b8b961) an alternative to GlusterD2